# Why is my custom delayed job initialized differently locally and on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, initialization, delayed-job

I have a custom job in Delayed Job:

```
class ImportJob < Struct.new(:my_datasource)
 include Apartment::Delayed::Job::Hooks

 def initialize(my_datasource)
  @database = Apartment::Database.current_database
  @my_datasource = my_datasource
 end

 def perform
  ...
 end
end
```

This works fine in development, but not on Heroku.

When debugging, I found out that in development the variables `database` and `my_datasource` were set properly, but in production (on Heroku), I had `@database` and `@my_datasource` available.

I can't understand why the same class doesn't initialize the same variables in the two environments.

Can anyone please shed some light and tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have workers running on Heroku? You need workers in order to run background processes.

Comment: Yes I do have a worker running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right solution, but I found out that Heroku was using Ruby 1.9.2 while I was using 1.9.3.

Upgrading to 1.9.3 on Heroku solved my problem.